# SQL Server 2005 Error, There is insufficient system memory to run this query

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Msg 701, Level 17, State 123, Line 1
There is insufficient system memory to run this query.
```

I have a query that uses Table-Valued function. I am calling the function several times.
Does this error mean I am running out of stack space? Or can I tune my SQL box memory settings to fix this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by redesigning my query to use 'Multi-Statement Function'
This type of TVF apparently creates a temporary table on disk, thus does not suffer from running out of memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's an enormous query, and/or there are lots of users using the system, each running large queries, this is inevitable.

Unfortunately, there's a known issue with SQL Server where this error happens even when the workload is the same as previously. Stopping/restarting the server, while completely ridiculous, often resolves the issue.

Another thing you could consider is to run the `dbcc free*cache` statements to clear out the memory taken up by caching.

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference taken from this blog !](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/11/sql-server-error-701-there-is-insufficient-system-memory-to-run-this-query/)**

There are different alternative to solve this problem.

**First,** Check your SQL Server setting for “min server memory” and “max server memory”. If you found very small difference in both the value, increase your “max server memory”.

**Second,** Found out long running queries with its memory usage information and if this query in idle states, please verify and kill this process. The database performance optimization is a major thing for memory usages.

**Third,** Found out index usages for long running queries because without proper indexing your system DISK I/O increase and its directly affect to your memory.

**Fourth,** Check the size of the Virtual memory paging file and increase the size of this file.

**Fifth,** Check the size of the “min memory per query” actually it is by default 1024 KB but in rare situations you can decrease the size of this parameter. Actually, this is not advisable, but you can try it.

**Sixth,** Try to execute this DBCC command and again this is not advisable because it may affect to the overall performance of the server. But you can try this.